# Copy data based on multiple if statements

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, copy-paste

I am getting a run time error '438': object doesn't support this property or method on the IF statements.
I am trying to copy data from one sheet to another given if all 4 if statements are met.

```
Sub update_cell1()

Dim lRow As Long

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 3 To lRow
   If Worksheets("TEST").Cells(i, 5).vlaue = Worksheets("Cell_1").cell(1, 2).Value Then 'B1
        If Worksheets("TEST").Cells(i, 1).vlaue = Worksheets("Cell_1").cell(1, 1).Value Then 'A1
            If Worksheets("TEST").Cells(i, 6).vlaue <> "" Then 'not blank
                If Worksheets("TEST").Cells(i, 8).vlaue <> "" Then 'not blank
                
                    Worksheets("TEST").Rows(i).Copy
                    Worksheets("Cell_1").Active
                    b = 5
                    Worksheets("Cell_1").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
                    ActiveSheet.Paste
                End If
            End If
        End If
      End If
    Next
    
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Worksheets("Cell_1").Active

End Sub
```

Comment: `.value` not `.vlaue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Worksheets(..).Cells(...).vlaue` should be corrected to `Worksheets(..).Cells(...).Value`

`Worksheets(..).cells(...)` should be corrected to `Worksheets(..).Cells(...)`

In VBA, properties are case-sensitive. That means `object.prop` is different than `object.Prop`

Comment: Thank you!! That seemed to fix it  Do you know why it might not like   Worksheets("CELL_1").Active  I did check the work sheet name is CELL_1

Comment: I don't understand what are you doing. `Worksheets("Cell_1").Active` isn't documented anywhere. If you are trying to set the active sheet, try `Worksheets(...).Activate`

Comment: I am trying to paste in to worksheet ("CELL_1")  starting at row 5  Worksheets("CELL_1").Active
                    b = 5
                    Worksheets("CELL_1").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
                    ActiveSheet.Paste

Answer (score 0):

Just syntax error - use **Cells()** instead of "cell()"